# When does a translation of a family of vectors span the same space as the untranslated vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ vectors of a (real) vector space $V$ and let $V_0 = \mathsf{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_k).$ Given $a \in V_0,$ consider $u_i = v_i - a$ the translated vectors.

> I want to find characterizations for $\mathsf{span}(u_1, \ldots, u_k) = V_0.$

There are trivial examples where the $(u_i)$ **do not** span $V_0$ such as when the $(v_i)$ is a basis and we select $a$ to be one of them. In fact, I am interested mainly in the case where $k$ is greater (strictly) than $\dim V_0.$

Here are some thoughts:

1. If $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k)$ are scalars such that $\sum \lambda_i = 1$ then $\sum \lambda_i u_i = \sum \lambda_i v_i - a;$
2. More generally to 1., if $\sum \lambda_i = \mu$ then $\sum \lambda_i u_i = \sum \lambda_i v_i - \mu a.$
3. So, intuitively the span of the $(u_i)$ is the translation of $V_0$ by $a,$ which of course lies within $V_0.$ This is of course not right but at least shows that the $(u_i)$ span a subspace of $V_0$ of codimension at most 1.

I am not sure what condition I am looking for but intuitively I would expect something like "if $k > \dim V_0$ and the $(v_i)$ are in 'general position' then the $(u_i)$ span $V_0$ as well" where "general position" would mean something like  any $k-1$ of the $(v_i)$ still span $V_0.$ Again, I am stuck and these are just some of my ideas.